# Converting multi column header df from wide to long format in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I would like to convert an excel file from wide format into long format.

I'm reading an excel file which has not only two rows of headers, it also includes merged cells in the header.
Input Example:

```
| Task | Name | May,2022  | Jun,2022  | Jul,2022  |
|      |      |status|type|status|type|status|type|
| ---- | ---- |------|----|------|----|------|----|
| 1    | Tom  |1     |AB  |1     |DT  |0     |AB  | 
| 2    | John |0     |DT  |1     |CC  |0     |GH  |
```

Desired Output:

| Task | Name | Date | status | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | May,2022 | 1 | AB |
| 1 | Tom | Jun,2022 | 1 | DT |
| 1 | Tom | Jul,2022 | 0 | AB |
| 2 | John | May,2022 | 0 | DT |
| 2 | John | Jun,2022 | 1 | CC |
| 2 | John | Jul,2022 | 0 | GH |

What i have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(path)
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Task","Name"],
     var_name="Date",
     value_name="Value")
```

I don't know how to deal with the multi header.
I tried combining the two headers.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(path, header[1,2])
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().ffill().values
df.columns.value[0]='Task'
df.columns.value[1]='Name'
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Task","Name"],
     var_name="Date",
     value_name="Value")
```

This results in having something like: (I'm fine with the date transformation)

| Task | Name | (2022-05-01 00:00:00, status) | (2022-05-01 00:00:00, type) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 1 | AB |
| 2 | John | 0 | DT |

The melt function returns a KeyError 'Task'.
Even if this would work i would somehow need to split the date from the status and type into seperate columns.
Someone knows how to deal with such data?

Comment: What exactly is your input? Can you provide a DataFrame constructor? Do you just want to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)?

Comment: If you can, share the excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_index` to preserve `Task` and `Name` columns then `stack` `Date` column and finally `reset_index` to get expected output:

```
>>> (df.set_index(['Task', 'Name']).rename_axis(columns=['Date', None])
       .stack(level=0).reset_index())

   Task  Name      Date  status type
0     1   Tom  Jul,2022       0   AB
1     1   Tom  Jun,2022       1   DT
2     1   Tom  May,2022       1   AB
3     2  John  Jul,2022       0   GH
4     2  John  Jun,2022       1   CC
5     2  John  May,2022       0   DT
```

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
data = {'index': [0, 1],
        'columns': [('Task', ''),
         ('Name', ''),
         ('May,2022', 'status'),
         ('May,2022', 'type'),
         ('Jun,2022', 'status'),
         ('Jun,2022', 'type'),
         ('Jul,2022', 'status'),
         ('Jul,2022', 'type')],
        'data': [[1, 'Tom', 1, 'AB', 1, 'DT', 0, 'AB'],
                 [2, 'John', 0, 'DT', 1, 'CC', 0, 'GH']],
        'index_names': [None],
        'column_names': [None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `index_col` and `header` for MulitIndex in index and columns first:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1])

print (df.index)
MultiIndex([(1,  'Tom'),
            (2, 'John')],
           names=['Task', 'Name'])

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('May,2022', 'status'),
            ('May,2022',   'type'),
            ('Jun,2022', 'status'),
            ('Jun,2022',   'type'),
            ('Jul,2022', 'status'),
            ('Jul,2022',   'type')],
           names=['Task', None])
```

So possible use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
out = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('Task','Name','Date')).reset_index()
print (out)
   Task  Name      Date  status type
0     1   Tom  Jul,2022       0   AB
1     1   Tom  Jun,2022       1   DT
2     1   Tom  May,2022       1   AB
3     2  John  Jul,2022       0   GH
4     2  John  Jun,2022       1   CC
5     2  John  May,2022       0   DT
```